# How project to 3D or 2D and plot multidimensional arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I project to 3D or 2D and plot multidimensional arrays in Java.

Is there any library that can do this?

I have 105 arrays with 105-dimensions each one.

Example:

[

6.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 4.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.0  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

]

Another:

[

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 6.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

]

I know they are long, but I would like plot these point in 3D or 2D.
How can I project them and plot them?

Comment: Arrays similar with those I put in the description. Their size is 105.

Comment: thinking about a 105d array makes my head hurt

Comment: And what kind of plot were you wanting?  I'm having difficulty visualising what output you want to have.

Comment: I need to project each point from 105d to 3d, for example. That's the part I don't know how to do id. Then I want plot the projected points.

Comment: Do you want it projected orthogonally to 102 of the axes?  Or do you want to view it at some multi-dimensional angle?

Comment: First option, project orthogonally.

Comment: Then all you have to do is choose which 102 entries to drop.  You are after a particular sub-array of the 105-entry array that you started with.  It's probably easiest just to build this manually.